# preserve bootstrap clicked tab on page refresh even if markup loaded by angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, my tabs are loaded using Angular. Whenever someone clicks on a tab I save the id to localStorage.

I want to click the same tab using jQuery when page refreshes, but the DOM element for the tab doesn't exist yet because Angular didn't load it yet. How can I run the click action after Angular is loaded?

Below is a snippet of my tab markup
markup below is loaded by Angular

```
<tabset>
  <tab id="tab1">
     <tab-heading></tab-heading>
  </tab>
  <tab id="tab2">
     <tab-heading></tab-heading>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I want to fire something like below after knowing the above markup is in the DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tab2').click();
});
```

Comment: Can't it be achieved with AngularJS? I doubt it is a good idea to mix jQuery with AngularJS for this.

Comment: I agree with @Regent

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use jQuery at all. In your case i suggest to use angular element in your controller.

```
angular.element('#tab2').trigger('click');
```